# XSLT Group by element value

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have a XML file, I need a XSL stylesheet to Group it and get output.

```
<Orders>
    <Order>
        <Client>1234</Client>
        <Amendments>True</Amendments>
        <Address>
            <ID>311</ID>
            <CompanyName>Test</CompanyName>
            <StreetAddress>Sri Lanka</StreetAddress>
        </Address>
        <Line>
            <Client>1234</Client>
            <ItemCode>B100V</ItemCode>
            <Cost>$2.00</Cost>
            <Qty>2</Qty>
            <Group>g2</Group>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <Client>1234</Client>
            <ItemCode>B102V</ItemCode>
            <Cost>$1.25</Cost>
            <Qty>4</Qty>
            <Group>g3</Group>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <Client>1234</Client>
            <ItemCode>B140V</ItemCode>
            <Cost>$3.05</Cost>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
            <Group>g1</Group>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <Client>1234</Client>
            <ItemCode>B113V</ItemCode>
            <Cost>$5.00</Cost>
            <Qty>5</Qty>
            <Group>g2</Group>
        </Line>
    </Order>
</Orders>
```

I need to display `ItemId` and `Cost` of each line group by `Group` node, and I need a linebreak for each group. Can anyone give help?

Please note my expected output:

```
1 of B140V - $3.05  $3.05
                    ------
                    $3.05

2 of B100V - $2.00  $4.00
5 of B113V - $5.00  $25.00
                    ------
                    $29.00

4 of B102V - $1.25  $5.00
                    ------
                    $5.00
```

Comment: I suggest you start here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html Then, if you still cannot make it work, post a **specific** question.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the quick solution:

Sample Input (XML with Multiple groups)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Orders>
   <Order>
      <Client>1234</Client>
      <Amendments>True</Amendments>
      <Address>
         <ID>311</ID>
         <CompanyName>Test</CompanyName>
         <StreetAddress>Sri Lanka</StreetAddress>
      </Address>
      <Line>
         <Client>1234</Client>
         <ItemCode>B100V</ItemCode>
         <Cost>$2.23</Cost>
         <Qty>2</Qty>
         <Group>g2</Group>
      </Line>
      <Line>
         <Client>1234</Client>
         <ItemCode>B102V</ItemCode>
         <Cost>$1.25</Cost>
         <Qty>4</Qty>
         <Group>g3</Group>
      </Line>
      <Line>
         <Client>1234</Client>
         <ItemCode>B102V</ItemCode>
         <Cost>$10.57</Cost>
         <Qty>10</Qty>
         <Group>g3</Group>
      </Line>
      <Line>
         <Client>1234</Client>
         <ItemCode>B140V</ItemCode>
         <Cost>$3.05</Cost>
         <Qty>1</Qty>
         <Group>g1</Group>
      </Line>
      <Line>
         <Client>1234</Client>
         <ItemCode>B140V</ItemCode>
         <Cost>$7.05</Cost>
         <Qty>7</Qty>
         <Group>g1</Group>
      </Line>
      <Line>
         <Client>1234</Client>
         <ItemCode>B113V</ItemCode>
         <Cost>$5.00</Cost>
         <Qty>5</Qty>
         <Group>g2</Group>
      </Line>
      <Line>
         <Client>1234</Client>
         <ItemCode>B113V</ItemCode>
         <Cost>$9.00</Cost>
         <Qty>6</Qty>
         <Group>g2</Group>
      </Line>
   </Order>
</Orders>

XSLT
```

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*" /> <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:key name="group" match="Line" use="Group" />
    <xsl:template match="Order">
        <AllUsers>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Line[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('group',Group)[1])]"/>
        </AllUsers>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Line">
         <Line>

            <xsl:for-each select="key('group',Group)">
 <Qty><xsl:value-of select="Qty" /></Qty> of <ItemCode><xsl:value-of select="ItemCode" /></ItemCode> - <Cost><xsl:value-of select="Cost" /></Cost>
<xsl:variable name="vTwice"> 
<xsl:call-template name="sumProducts">
        <xsl:with-param name="mul1" select="Qty"/>
<xsl:with-param name="mul2" select="substring-after(Cost,'$')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="$vTwice"/>
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each><xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>------
<xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
<xsl:variable name="test">
<xsl:for-each select="key('group',Group)"><mine>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(Cost,'$') * Qty"/></mine>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
 <total>
            <xsl:variable name="myTotal" select="exslt:node-set($test)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('$',format-number(sum($myTotal/mine),'#.00'))" />
        </total>

<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
          </Line>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="sumProducts">
        <xsl:param name="mul1"/>
        <xsl:param name="mul2"/> <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>  
<result><xsl:value-of select='concat("$",format-number(($mul1 * $mul2), "#.00"))'/></result>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Got the below result:

```html
2 of B100V - $2.23 $4.46
5 of B113V - $5.00 $25.00
6 of B113V - $9.00 $54.00
   ------
   $83.46
4 of B102V - $1.25 $5.00
10 of B102V - $10.57 $105.70
   ------
   $110.70
1 of B140V - $3.05 $3.05
7 of B140V - $7.05 $49.35
   ------
   $52.40
```

Comment: This is a good start, but it seems that it will not work if there are more than two `<Line>` with the same `<Group>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I'll check this and let you know.

Comment: @Jokab - It works fine. Let me know if it fails in particular case

Comment: @Kasun - Please accept answer if it produces proper output